# Renderscript issue live wallpaper Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, importerror, renderscript

I've just opened the source for a live wallpaper app in eclipse. It is a wallpaper which is included in the CM11 sources, so I know it should compile fine, however, in eclipse I get the "Import cannot be resolved" error on the following imports:

```
import android.renderscript.RenderScriptGL;
import android.renderscript.ProgramStore.*;
```

The last import isn't literally that, the * is either BlendDstFunc, BlendSrcFunc or DepthFunc, but the error is about the ProgramStore part of the declaration. All other android.renderscript includes are recognized just fine since I've set the enivironment to build using API level 20. I read somewhere that these functions are deprecated, but if that's the problem I would expect a deprecated warning, not these errors. I can see both the RenderScriptGL.java and the ProgramStore.java files in the /android/renderscript folders of the sdk and all the other imports for renderscript are working fine. What's going on here? If it is a deprecated class, what are the alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProgramStore is marked @hide, and thus is not a public API (nor has it ever been public). RenderScriptGL is deprecated (as you mentioned), but it still works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I noticed the RenderScriptGL also has the hide attribute besides the deprecated one. Does this mean I have to rewrite the entire project to use java reflection for the used functions from these classes or is there an easier way to access these classes?

Comment: You really shouldn't start any new projects with RenderScriptGL, unless you are sure that you need it. If you are targeting an older SDK level, you won't need to use reflection, but if you attempt to target Android L or higher, you will have to use reflection to access all of these hidden classes/methods.

Comment: That's the problem, it isn't a new project, it's an app which is part of the CM11 sources which I want to edit. So RenderScriptGL is already part of the source and I just want to be able to compile it. Thanks for the replies though, you've been a great help!